# Can an extended class tell its super function to use a certain class

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

lets say you have class representing a gun and a class representing a bullet.
Can a class extending the gun, have its own specific extended bullet class and the gun superclass can handle an array of them.

in this example I have two Gun extended classes, each want to use a different type of bullet extended class but have the super handle the adding to the array (to avoid a bunch of code duplication)

psudo:

```
class Gun{
    ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;

    Gun(x,y,z){
    }

    void shoot(){
        //add bullet to bullets array
    }

}

class CustomGun extends Gun{
    CustomGun(x,y,z){
        //do stuff
    }
    //want super.shoot() to add CustomBullet to bullets array

}

class CustomGunTwo extends Gun{
    CustomGunTwo(x,y,z){
        //do stuff
    }
    //want super.shoot() to add CustomBulletTwo to bullets array


}

class Bullet{
    Bullet(x,y,z){
        //do stuff
    }
}

class CustomBullet extends Bullet{
    CustomBullet(x,y,z){
        super(x, y, z)
    }
}
class CustomBulletTwo extends Bullet{
    CustomBullet(x,y,z){
        super(x, y, z)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Jens

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter the behavior of a method in a superclass.  But you can override it, and implement a different behavior (in the subclass).  The superclass needs to be implemented approriately for this to happen.

In your example, you have left `bullets` with *package private* access, so the method in `CustomGunTwo` could insert custom bullets into the list.  If `bullets` had *private* that wouldn't be possible.

But consider this:

```
public class Gun {
    private ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;

    public void shoot(){
        load(new Bullet());
    }

    protected void load(Bullet bullet) {
        bullets.add(bullet);
    }
}

public class CustomGun extends Gun {
    @Override
    public void shoot() {
        load(new CustomBullet());
    }
}
```

Here we have *designed* the `Gun` class to allow for subclasses to modify the loading behavior.

Comment: I like that :)
Thank you